# This question is from my discrete math. So far i have no idea how to solve it. Can anyone help me with this?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[image]
Let n be a prime.   1. If (G,+) has order 2n, prove that every proper subgroup of (G,+) is cyclic.   2. If (G,+) has order n^2, prove that (G,+) has a subgroup of order n.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question

Answer (score 3):

For part $1$ a proper subgroup would be trivial or have prime order, every group of prime order is cyclic.

For part $b$ take a non-trivial element and consider the generated subgroup by that element, by lagrange the order can be $n$ or $n^2$ (since $n$ is prime). If the order is $n$ we are done, if the order is $n^2$ then that subgroup is $G$ and so $G$ is generated by that element,so $G$ is cyclic.

A cyclic group $G$ has exactly one subgroup of every order that divides the order of $G$